# Routing Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"link_devices", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error, it seems like Link_device 'id can be null. But i checked the database, i did not see any link_device id is nil;

Any suggestions?

```
<th>
    <%= dns_record_set.name %>
    <small>
        <% if dns_record_set.interface %>
            <%= link_to dns_record_set.interface.link_device, link_device_path(dns_record_set.interface.link_device) %>
        <% end %>
    </small>
</th>
```

Comment: Please post your routes and the log generated.

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and post the results here.

Comment: People answering with conditional checks without any data from OP. I think we should know what link_device gives. Then we should go for that conditional check only if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition for `link_device` also if that is present with `interface`. like below -

```
<% if dns_record_set.interface && dns_record_set.interface.link_device %>
```

Comment: Thank you! its work!! One more question,....  Except add condition for Link_device, is there another way to make the result only show link_device which has an id.

Comment: using `persisted?` you can check if object has an `id`. like - `<% if dns_record_set.interface && dns_record_set.interface.link_device.persisted? %>`